# Holding information about table reservations PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a website allowing me to book a table at a restaurant. However, i'm struggling with how I will hold this information.

In my database, I have a booking table which holds the Date and Time of the booking of the table (It is assumed all the bookings last 2 hours)

I have a 'Table' table which holds the table id, the capacity of the table e.g 3 seats and the quantity of that type of table.
(I also have many other tables include restaurant, openinghours, customer etc.)

I'm not sure how to show this on PHP to allow a user to book a time which hasn't been fully booked. I want it to show every 2 hours from the opening time of the restaurant to the closing time in PHP, taking away the ones in which the maximum tables have been booked for. How would I go about doing this restaurant table booking? I'd have a drop down of selection box to select which day, which will show the available times.

Do I need to change my tables, and how would I go about this in PHP?  ( I already know how to connect to the database and pull the data down, just how i'd show it and show the times etc.)

Comment: I've got pages to show off the restaurant information and such, I just need the table booking part of it sorted out. Just some suggestions on how I could store this and produce this information a web page to show the time slots.

Comment: Since I promised to look at it, here is my suggestion, this is not complicated task but at the same time your question missing a lot details and non code is done, so it simply asking for full solution, almost no thing is clear, If I need to do it, I have to do your ER design, CSS, HTML and PHP coding. Therefore I can not see my motivation doing it. I suggest you to hire some local programmer to do it OR do what you can do and ask specific questions regarding the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a little bit logic thinking. Here are a few PHP time and date suggestions. If you have some questions, feel free to ask.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Zagreb');
$datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$day = date("D");
$hour = date("H");



$open  = array("Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun");
$close = array("Mon");

$open_hour  = "9";
$close_hour = "23";



if (in_array("$day", $open) && $open_hour > $hour && $close_hour < $hour) {

    echo "Open"."<br>";

}elseif (in_array("$day", $close)) {

    echo "Closed"."<br>";

}








//it's a Tuseday
echo $which_day = date('D', strtotime("2016-02-16"))."<br>";





//example if this date is booked
$booked = "2016-02-16 20:00";

echo "You can only book 2 hour befor ".$book_before = date("Y-m-d H.i",strtotime("$booked - 2 hour"))."<br>";


echo "".$booked."<br>";


echo "You can only book 2 hour after ".$book_after = date("Y-m-d H.i",strtotime("$booked + 2 hour"))."<br>";
```

Comment: do you think this is a soltuion